# How do I add integers to char[] array?

Tags: c#

So I have to write a code that picks our random numbers from 1 to 100 and add them to a char[] array. But I'm having some difficulty doing so as I can only add the numbers to the array if I convert them to a char using (char) which changes the number. Can someone please help me?
Thanks,

```
 public char[] CreationListe(int nmbrevaleurTirés)
    {
        char[] l = new char[nmbrevaleurTirés];
        for (int i = 0; i < nmbrevaleurTirés; i++)
        {
            l[i] = (char)(new Random().Next(1, 101));

        }
        return l;
    }
```

Comment: _So I have to write a code that picks our random numbers from 1 to 100 and add them to a char[] array_ - may I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: How are you supposed to represent the number 100 as a `char`? The char with the ASCII value of 100? What about 8? The character `8` or the ASCII character 8 (backspace)?

Comment: also note that ever random number will be the same, move the `new Randon` out of the loop

Comment: Also, don’t create a new `Random` within the loop, or you may get repeated values. Create one outside the loop.

Comment: @DStanley Ehsan's answer shows how, stores values up to 32k, I was surprised

Comment: Modern .net doesn't seed Random from the clock, so it's less prone to this "created a Random insiode a loop and got 2000 identical values out of it before it changed" caused by creating it inside a loop. Still shouldn't be done, of course, because it's a waste of good CPU cycles..

Comment: *How do I add integers to char[] array?* - you add them to an int array..

Answer (score 2):

use ToChar() method of Convert class.

Convert.ToChar(new Random().Next(1, 101))

Comment: there is no Int.ToChar method

Comment: sorry. I edit answer

Comment: In what way is this different from casting to `char`?

Comment: @pm100 erm. `(char)9` is not `'9'`, it's a tab like `\t` and `\x9`. `'\9'` is an unrecognized escape sequence. `Convert.ToChar(9)` is also a tab, and hence equivalent to `(char)9`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/5xBCSv

Comment: Post your try, something is wonky

Comment: @CaiusJard - totally correct, my test was BS -- walk of shame

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert an `integer` larger then `9` into a `char` because it's considered as 2 `chars`, i.e. `10` will be considered as `1` and `0`.

so I would recommend adding it to an `array` of `strings`

(except if your trying to get a random charcode which I dont think is the case, because why till 100?)

Comment: Array of ints, surely

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use an `int[]` array instead

There shouldn't be any problem in storing ints up to 65535 in a `char` but you will have to cast it back to an `int` if you don't want it to be weird:

```
public static void Main()
{
   var x = CreationListe(200);
   foreach(var c in x)
     Console.WriteLine((int)c);  //need to cast to int!
    
}

public static char[] CreationListe(int nmbrevaleurTirés)
{
    char[] l = new char[nmbrevaleurTirés];
    for (int i = 0; i < nmbrevaleurTirés; i++)
    {
        l[i] = (char)(new Random().Next(1, 65536));

    }
    return l;
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/z5yoBn

If you don't cast it back to int, then you'll get the char at that character index in the unicode table. If you've put `65` into a char, you'll get `A` when you print it, for example. This is because `A` is at position 65 in the table:

[image: ascii table]

(ASCII table image posted for brevity's sake)